# fo:leader-pattern with padding from the top of its parent element?

Tags: xml, stylesheet, dita, xmetal

I'm trying to implement a custom word element in XLST.

The custom word element:
[image]

To implement this, it seemed appropriate to use the fo:leader element as the border must span 100% of its parent.

XLST:

```
    <xsl:template match="reader-note">
    <xsl:variable name="txtNote" select="'NOTE'"/>
    <fo:block margin-top="5px" text-align="center" width="100%">
       <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"  leader-length.minimum="100%" width="100%"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$txtNote"/>
        <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots" width="100%"/>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block border-bottom="1px dashed black" padding-bottom="10px" padding-top="10px" text-align="center" >
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>            
    </fo:block>

</xsl:template>
```

On transforming the XML file with the XLST above, it outputs as:

[image: Current output when transformed]

As shown in the image above, the leading-pattern of the "NOTE" text begins at the bottom. I want this to appear 50% from the top of the "NOTE" text. I have tried various padding & margin attributes around the text and nothing has worked.

Does anyone have a suggestion how I could implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the block to justify the text, not center it. Then it will stretch.